# Consume Kafka messages from two different topics where TopicA and TopicB have some information and want to read data paralley without lag.

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, service, .net-6.0

Consume Kafka messages from two different topics where TopicA has some information and TopicB has some information and wants to read data parallelly without any lag (these two topics also have relationships).
I'd like to read data from TopicA's 1st record and TopicB's 1st record, and in the same way, 2nd with 2nd record ...., How can I achieve these while consuming data?

Thanks

Consume Kafka messages from two different topics

Answer (score 0):

You could use to fetch a specific message at a particular offset. Assuming messages are nicely an evenly distributed across topics.

However this is very brittle as you cannot control/reset the offset in case you need to. Better would it to have data in both message types that are linked. This could be a unique transaction reference or something else that guarantees uniqueness.

Via stream processing you could combine both streams. With [KSQLDB](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/joins/join-streams-and-tables/) this is pretty easy although the result is limited to another Kafka topic (or derived result, like a table)